# Shared preference failing to find already created keys

Tags: java, android

The following code is piece of code which handles presistence of two vars in SharedPreference. When I run the app first time, it successfully save the vars' values.(editor.commit returned TRUE). When I quit the app and restart,
settings.contains is failing to find my two vars/keys which I already created on the first run, in shared preferences.As a result my app creating another values, which is not supposed to (going to else condition).

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences settings = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();


    if (settings.contains("passug1"))
        Passug1=settings.getString("passug1","");
    else {
        sendJson1();
        editor = settings.edit();
        //sendJson1();
        editor.putString("passug1", Passug1);
        if (editor.commit())
            System.out.println("Successfully saved");
        else
            System.out.println("Not saved");
        //editor.apply();
    }
    if (settings.contains("passug2"))
        Passug2=settings.getString("passug2","");
    else
    {
        sendJson2();
        editor = settings.edit();
        //sendJson2();
        editor.putString("passug2", Passug2);
        if (editor.commit())
            System.out.println("Successfully saved");
        else
            System.out.println("Not saved");
        //editor.commit();
        //editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: Should I create an xml for shared prefernces in advance somewhere? I did not do that.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] which any of us can compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

After testing your code, it appears to me the only reason why nothing is being saved to your preferences is because your `Passug1` and `Passug2` fields are null and therefore you are saving null values to the preferences. Passing null values to `putString` will actually delete any existing values with that key. If your `sendJson1()` and `sendJson2()` methods are *intended* to assign a value to `Passug1` and `Passug2` you should check to see if they are operating correctly.

Secondly, you are using `System.out.println` in your code which will normally not output anything in the normal logcat Android log system which might be making it difficult for you to determine if your code is working or not. You should use the methods in the `android.util.Log` class in order to do your logging.

Finally, your initial call to `settings.edit()` is redundant.